# Why does the manual to my floor fan tell me to pull out the cord whenever it's not in use?

Tags: consumer-electronics, fan

In the manual to my just-bought floor fan, it says this (among many other weird requirements/expectations):

> Pull out the plug from the power point when the product is not in use. Do not pull the power cord to pull out the plug.

Why do they tell me this? If I don't use the fan, I turn it off with the knob on the fan. I don't pull out the actual stick/cord from the wall. That's insanity.

Possibly, I would do it if I'm going away for weeks/months/years, just because it "feels" like a reasonable thing to do (without really understanding why), but over night or just when I'm not in the kitchen (where it's located)? Why would one do that? That would cause an insane amount of wear and tear on the cable/connector, and be a massive PITA for me.

They don't explain with one word why this would be necessary/good, so that's what I'm asking.

Comment: Because it reduces the risk of failure that could cause a fire.

Comment: reduces a potential trip hazard

Comment: Note that in a US workplace one needs to follow OSHA 1910.303(b)(2) and install and use equipment in accordance with instructions included in the listing and labeling. One key reason is floor fans are moved around, often put on extension cords, and that raises a number of possible issues with OSHA.

Comment: @SolarMike it does, only in the sense that it reduces it to zero from  1E(-10) .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft so pet knocks it? seen that happen... Kid plays with it and gets fingers pinched - seen that (older fan though). 1E(-10) really... I must be **so** unlucky or statistically blessed to come across those events.

Answer (score 5):

#### No good reason

Probably the legal department decided it was a little safer to not have power to the device all the time.  Practically, there is no reason to do this.

Comment: Outside North America, plenty of countries have individual switches on AC outlets, so removing power _without_ removing the plug is also an option - with the advantage of not causing wear-and-tear on the plug, receptacle, or cable.

Comment: @Dai but you have no way of knowing by mere visual examination whether or not the outlet is hot.  Unplugging the fan guarantees it can't run.

Comment: I concur...under "most circumstances" or in "reasonable settings". However, in the USA, the manufacturer has to assume that the customer is definitely NOT being reasonable. Or the circumstances might be "special". For example, rodents might chew through the cable which could then pose an electrical hazard or cause a fire. While this can also happen while the device is in use, the manual possibly also mentions that the device must be kept under close supervision when in use. You might consider to elaborate on that in your answer to turn it into a better answer.

Comment: @Klaws, and then you shock yourself when you touch the chewed wire.  These what-if scenarios are not part of the normal world.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the primary intention of the statement. When disconnecting the wiring to remove the fan from use, **manipulate the plug directly, do not use the wire to apply tension to the plug**